# Consume message when ready with Masstransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

I might be wrong here but I couldn't see any way to consume a message with Masstransit when I'm ready, rather just have a consumer class that gets called when we do have a message to consume?

Is there a way to basically not consume anything until requested? Similar to how the RabbitMQ client library has basicget?

Right now I have this setup:

```
public class LoaderConsumer : IConsumer<LoadQueueItemCommand>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<LoadQueueItemCommand> context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But what if in another area of the application I'm depending on it and want to consume it there?

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit only supports "push" delivery of messages from the transport to consumers. MassTransit does not provide any methods/interfaces for "pulling" a message from the transport.